# Construct a single table with a loop with R and Rfacebook package

Tags: facebook, r, loops, facebook-graph-api, append

I use Rfacebook package to download Facebook Fanpages posts . I also want to get the comments and likes of the posts, but I only have working code to get single comments and I fail to create a loop.

I ll post all steps one by one and keep my token updated for the next several hours.

```
#Step1
install.packages("Rfacebook")
install.packages("Rook")
install.packages("igraph")

#start the libaries
library(Rfacebook)
library(Rook)
library(igraph)
```

After installtion I can generate a token (use mine) and download the FB page humans of new york for example:

```
#step 2
#browse to facebook and ask for token
#browseURL("https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer")

token <- "CAACEdEose0cBACzNgrHPBIZAQCQ8EZBpGJqwwT8uVq74ONdKJKDk6fiXXgjBB4ZBHC93Njd2onrhGsiffK5QFqpIvZBCFEagBkOqMgjaf103XwpHhSV6YOeVdcjU813g6eJKCsdtNT7pGRYftTXgZBrSMMOyAj47mAZBGxI98iPv78qTeIqliA8UCbZBzZAVU0NoOUBTkJSPPQZDZD"

#get FB fanpage "humansofnewyork"
humansofnewyork <- getPage("humansofnewyork", token, n=500)
```

Now I want to create a loop that will download every comment and like for every postid. But when I run a  loop append I will get a table which will replicate the colomuns horizontally at certain point instead of just adding rows vertically.

```
users.humansofnewyork = c()

   for (i in 1:3) {
  users.humansofnewyork = append(users.humansofnewyork, getPost( (humansofnewyork$id[i]) , token, n = 500, comments = TRUE,likes = TRUE, n.likes=500, n.comments=500))
}
```

I would be so glad if someone can help me.

Kind regards

Comment: I'm unclear what you're asking. Maybe post a sample of your actual output and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

use 'plyr' package in R, which helps in splitting the data. It has helped me till this moment.

use the following code

```
apply<-ldply(users.humansofnewyork,data.frame)
```